# Retrieve different labeled vertices, AND/OR between vertices properties

Tags: acl, graph-databases, gremlin, janusgraph

below is my graph

```
 g.addV('user').property('userId','user1').as('u1').
      addV('user').property('userId','user2').as('u2').
      addV('user').property('userId','user3').as('u3').
      addV('group').property('groupId','group1').as('g1').
      addV('group').property('groupId','group2').as('g2').
      addV('group').property('groupId','group3').as('g3').
      addV('folder').property('folderId','folder1').property('folderName','level1_1').property('description','level1_desc1').as('f1').
      addV('folder').property('folderId','folder2').property('folderName','level2_2').property('description','level2_desc2').as('f2').
      addV('folder').property('folderId','folder3').property('folderName','level3_3').property('description','level3_desc3').as('f3').
      addV('object').property('objId','obj1').property('objTitle','objtitle1_1').property('description','o1_desc1').as('o1').
      addV('object').property('objId','obj2').property('objTitle','objtitle2_2').property('description','o2_desc2').as('o2').
      addV('object').property('objId','obj3').property('objTitle','objtitle3_3').property('description','o3_desc3').as('o3').
      addE('in_folder').from('o1').to('f2').
      addE('in_folder').from('o2').to('f3').
      addE('in_folder').from('o1').to('f3').
      addE('in_folder').from('f2').to('f1').
      addE('in_folder').from('f3').to('f2').
      addE('member_of').from('u1').to('g1').
      addE('member_of').from('u2').to('g2').
      addE('member_of').from('u3').to('g3').
      addE('member_of').from('g3').to('g1').
      addE('has_permission').from('g1').to('f1').
      addE('has_permission').from('g1').to('f1').
      addE('has_permission').from('g2').to('f2').
      addE('has_permission').from('g3').to('f3').
      addE('has_permission').from('u2').to('f1').iterate()
```

Two questions on the graph

**#1 - how do i retrieve all the folders and objects where user have access in single query**

```
g.V().has('user','userId','user1').emit().until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).repeat(out('member_of')).outE('has_permission').inV().as('f').inE('in_folder').outV().as('a').select('a','f').range(1,20)
```

but this query results in each object and its folder vertex instead my expectation is to receive like a search results considering folders and objects as search result ?

**#2 - get object vertices's based object vertex property OR folder vertex property in hierarchy, meaning all the objects are reachable based on folder vertex property at any level.**

i have written below query which returns results when both folder and object vertex property values matches.

```
g.V().has('user','userId','user1').emit().until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).repeat(out('member_of')).outE('has_permission').inV().has('folderName',textContains('level1')).inE('in').outV().has('objTitle',textContains('objtitle3')).as('o').select('o').valueMap('objTitle','objId').dedup().range(1,20)
```

How can i do OR between object and folder vertex properties and how to do OR on multiple properties of folder and object vertices's ?

Comment: Can you give more details about the second question? Such as expected results or a figure to describe the question.

Comment: Retrieve objects based on property values of folder vertices OR object self property values. in the query what i have written , getting objects which matches both folderName property text AND objTitle property text. how do i make this to OR clause to match either of the text's. The query shows one field from each vertex type, but in real time multiple property values needs to checked with OR clause between them.

Comment: the query i have written should return results when .has('folderName',textContains('fake')) supplied as still object text is matching with some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#1 - how do i retrieve all the folders and objects where user have access in single query**

```
g.V().has('user','userId','user1').
repeat(out('member_of')).emit().
until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
out('has_permission').dedup().
union(
// all folders
identity(),
// all sub-folders and objects
__.repeat(__.in('in_folder')).emit().until(__.not(inE('in_folder')))
).dedup()
```

Comment: Hi Sel, with above query im getting an error.   `No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.indentify() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: identity(groovy.lang.Closure), notify()`

Comment: `graph=JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cql-es-server.properties')` Using Janusgraph factory to get the traversal object.

Comment: It should be identity() and not indentify().